# Express route not working

Tags: node.js, express

I am using express as server and in the last few days i tried to make a new routes under the "localhost:3000/app/home" path. The problem is that i receive a 404 error from the server when i open this path. i am sure that the file exist, so i think that the problem is the route configuration of express.

**App.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var session = require('express-session');

var index = require('./routes/index');
var app_index = require('./routes/app');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(session({ secret: 'ashasjasdiw', resave: true, saveUninitialized: false }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/app', app_index);


// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});
app.listen(3000);
module.exports = app;
```

this is my route **App.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/app', function(req, res){
  res.render('app/home');
});
module.exports = router;
```

I use a redirect to go under the path "/app/home" and i don't know if it's the best way to do that.
this is the error page:
[image]

Comment: What you are hitting in the browser?

Comment: i fill a login form and then if the data is right the server redirect me to this page

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are mounting the route `/app` on the application's `/app`.  The resultant route is therefore `/app/app` not `/app/home`. If you wish to access the route from `/app/home` you will need to change the route to `/home`.

```
router.get('/home', function(req, res){
```

Answer (score 6):

I think you might need to remove the `app` from the route in `app.js`

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render('app/home');
});
module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. I finally realized that in your app.js file (main file) you use `app.use('/api','./routes/index');`. When you go into your index.js file, your `router.get`, `router.post`, `router.put` etc. need to be `router.get('/', function(...))` which will refer to your `http://localhost/api`!